# Java, el programa no sigue las llamadas a métodos desde otros métodos

Tags: java, metodos

tengo el código que muestro a continuación (Hay tres clases aparte dentro del mismo package pero no parecen dar problema alguno por lo que no las adjunto en el código), la cuestión es que no encuentro la forma de seguir con el programa si se intenta llamar al metodo en diversos puntos del mismo. Se queda el programa como pensando si se dan las opciones que cito delante de // en el código. Por favor, si alguien ve donde está fallando lo agradecería mucho. Además de eso, estoy haciendo de forma correcta la llamada a esoss métodos o debería tratar de hacerlo desde el main() ? GRACIAS.

```
package UF2.Examen_v2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Examen2
{


    public static double[] notes = new double[50];
    public int MARCA_NOTES = -1;
    public int NUM_NOTES = 0;
    public String MARCA_FI = "fi";
    private boolean fi = false;
    public double max = 0;
    public double min = 0;
    public double mitj = 0;


    private final CalculArrays calculador = new CalculArrays();
    private final CercaDicotomica cerca = new CercaDicotomica();
    private final NotaAText transformar = new NotaAText();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Examen2 programa = new Examen2();
        programa.inici();
        programa.PreguntarNotes();
    }

    public void inici(){
        
        System.out.println("\nBenvinguda al programa d'emmagatzematge i calcul de notes:\n");
    }


    private void PreguntarNotes() {

        System.out.println("\nAbans de comenÃ§ar, escriu tantes notes ENTERES com vulguis.");
        System.out.println("\nQuan hagis acabat d'escriure les notes, escriu un -1.");
        System .out.println("--------------------------------------");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     
            for(int i =0;i<notes.length;i++) {
                notes[i]=sc.nextDouble();
                NUM_NOTES=NUM_NOTES+1;
                if(sc.hasNextDouble()==false){ **//1: Si ejecuta este if ejecuta el metodo 
                                               //PreguntarNotes() pero luego no sigue el 
                                               //programa, es decir no ejecuta el método 
                                               //ImprimirArrayNotes()**
                System.out.print("Alguna de les dades entrades no es un ENTER, torna a 
                començar:\n\n"); ***// Además aunque no entre en este primer if y etre en el 
                                 //siguiente tampoco continua el programa, PreguntarNotes();                                                                     
                                 //En cambio si elimino todo el primer if, funciona el 
                                 //programa sin problemas*****
                }else if(notes[i]==-1) { 
                            
                    ImprimirArrayNotes();
                    
                }
            }
    }
 
    private void ImprimirArrayNotes() {
     
        System.out.print("L'array de notes avaluat es: [");
        for(int i=0;i<NUM_NOTES-1;i++) {
            System.out.print(notes[i]+", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]\n\n");
        
        MostrarMenu();
    }


    private void MostrarMenu() {
        System.out.println("\nBenvinguda al cÃ lcul de notes de classe.");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("[MAX] Saber la nota mÃ xima de classe");
        System.out.println("[MIN] Saber la nota mÃ­nima de classe");
        System.out.println("[MIT] Saber la nota mitjana de classe");
        System.out.println("[FI] Sortir.");
        System.out.print("OpciÃ³: ");
        
        TractarOpcio();
    }

    private void TractarOpcio() {
        
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String opcio=sc.next();
        sc.close();
        
        double []nouArrayNotes=new double[NUM_NOTES-1];
        
        for(int i=0;i<NUM_NOTES-1;i++) {
            
            nouArrayNotes[i]=notes[i];
        }
        
        double notaPostCalc=0;
        
        
       if(opcio.equalsIgnoreCase("MAX")) {
            notaPostCalc=calculador.calcularMaxim(nouArrayNotes);
            
            
            
        }else if(opcio.equalsIgnoreCase("MIN")) {
            notaPostCalc=calculador.calcularMinim(nouArrayNotes);
            
            
        }else if(opcio.equalsIgnoreCase("MIT")) {
            notaPostCalc=calculador.calcularMitjana(nouArrayNotes,NUM_NOTES);
            
        }else if(opcio.equalsIgnoreCase("FI")){
            
            System.out.print("Fins la pròxima!");
            System.exit(0);
            
        }else{
             System.out.print("L'opció introduïda es incorrecte, torna-ho a provar\n");
            TractarOpcio(); ***//Aquí si se da este else da error del Scanner.***  
        }  
       
       
       String NotaAcaracter=PrepararSortida(notaPostCalc);
       
       
       ImprimirResultat(notaPostCalc,NotaAcaracter,opcio);
       
    }
        

    private String PrepararSortida(double valor) {
        
        String notaAlletres=transformar.notaAText(valor);
        return notaAlletres;
    }

  
    private boolean MirarSiAlgu8() {
        
        
        int Algu8=cerca.cercaDicotomica(notes, 0, NUM_NOTES, 8);
        boolean trobat=true;
            
        if(Algu8!=-1) {
            
            trobat=true;
        }else {
            
            trobat=false;
        }
        
        return trobat;
    }

   
    private void ImprimirResultat(double valornota, String text, String opcio) {
        
                
        String opcioescollida = "";
        if (opcio.equalsIgnoreCase("MAX")){
            opcioescollida = "mÃ xim";
        }
        else if (opcio.equalsIgnoreCase("MIN")){
            opcioescollida = "mÃ­nim";
        }
        else {
            opcioescollida = "mitjÃ ";
        }
        System.out.print("El valor " + opcioescollida +" de l'array que has escrit Ã©s " + valornota);
        System.out.println(" que equival a un " + text + ".\n");
        
       boolean Troba=MirarSiAlgu8();
        
        if(Troba==true) {
            System.out.println("A mÃ©s el nÃºmero 8 es troba dins les notes! Felicitats! ");
        }else {
            
            System.out.println("El numero 8 no es troba dins les notes.\n\n");
        }
        
       inici(); ***//Llama a inicio() y ejecuta pero no sigue la siguiente llamada a 
                //PreguntarNotes()***
    }

}
```

Comment: Y porque deberia llamar a PreguntarNotes, si el metodo inici solo imprime un menu? el programa hace exactamente lo que pensas... Igual, no deberias volver a llamar a ese metodo, tu metodo deberia retornar algo.. y si quieres que se imprima de vuelta un menu, deberias meterlo en una iteracion (tal vez un while?)... pero este codigo es funcional y hace lo que tiene que hacer.

Comment: Fijate que tu main hace 2 llamadas... tal vez eso es lo que tenes que repetir, hasta que el usuario decida salir...

Comment: Primero gracias por contestar @gbianchi , quiero que llame a PreguntarNotes() porque ese if hace referencia al caso en el que el usuario ha introducido un dato que no es un double , que es lo esperado para el array, entonces el programa le pediría que vuelva a introducir los datos y por ende , se vuelva a ejecutar el método preguntarNotes() pero no entiendo porque no lo hace, y en su lugar se queda esperando instrucción.

Comment: En caso de que se introduzcan los datos correctamente (es decir un seguido de double's) hasta que se introduzca -1 el programa llamaría a otro método ImprimirArrayNotes() y seguiría con el programa, eso tampoco lo hace mientras exista el primer if que condiciona que el tipo de datos entrado sea el correcto. Si elimino ese if si que salta al siguiente método ImprimirArrayNotes .

Comment: Estás ejecutando `sc.nextDouble()` dos veces en `PreguntarNotes`, una en el `for` y otra en el `if`. Esto es, estás pidiendo dos veces el ingreso del caracter, supongo que esa no era tu intención.

Comment: Tenes problemas de logica. un if se ejecuta una sola vez.. que pasa si puso un valor incorrecto? entende los comentarios que te dejamos, y refactoriza tu codigo para que siga una linea logica.

Comment: Hola @GavilanPatagonico en PreguntarNotes ejecuto una vez el sc.nextDouble()  en el for y en el if ejecuto un sc.hasNextDouble que devuelve un booleano , uno es para leer datos (sc.nextDouble()) y el otro es para ver si devuelve un true o un false...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, no puedo refactorizar mi código si aún no tengo la respuesta. Simplemente pregunto porque se detiene el código y no sigue ejecutándose quedandose pausado, como esperando instrucción cuando la instrucción a ejecutar sería (según entiendo) seguir con la llamada al siguiente método que le indico? No se puede ejecutar un if y de cumplirse repetir la ejecución del mismo método?¿?¿ volviendose a repetir el mismo if una y 1000 veces hasta que el usuario introduzca los valores deseados?¿

Comment: No.. segui tu codigo.. una vez que llams a inici, que mas queres que haga, y porque queres que haga eso?

Comment: nextDouble() lee y avanza. Cuando llamas a hasNextDouble estas en la siguiente posición de sc. Esto debería ser simple de comprobar, ingresando dos veces seguidas -1 el método debería funcionar. Probá al revés, primero preguntá `hasNextDouble()` (que no avanza), y luego asigná la variable con `nextDouble()` (que avanza).

Comment: ahaaaa gracias @GavilanPatagonico no me di cuenta , hasNextDouble() me estaba mandando otra vez a nextDouble() !! Ahora si me funciona esa parte! Sabrías como puedo solucionar las otras dos partes que me fallan? 1º en el TractarOpcio() el último else{   ahí me lee el print pero luego me lanza error (java.util.NoSuchElementException) ahí querría que si ninguna de las opciones introducidas coincide vuelva a lanzar el TractarOpcio() de nuevo . Y 2º por ultimo al final del programa como puedo hacer para que vuelva a empezar, ya que si llamo a la función inici() me lanza el mismo tipo de error.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné todo , estaba finalizando el Scanner cuando no debía hacerlo por si se reiniciaba el programa. Muchas gracias @GavilanPatagonico me has solucionado la duda!